# How to call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo on click on center button of rotary wheel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing Rotary wheel button as an Recording button in my Camera . But on Click the Center button of rotary DidFinish method is not calling .

Rotary wheel use from http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit#comments

Probelm is that , In MyCameraViewController ,I am adding rotating wheel and start video recording automatically , Right now I want to stop video recording from Center button of rotary wheel.

Please give some clue ,How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this method to SMRotaryProtocol.h and call this method every time a touch in the middle is detected.

As I see in source code, author didn't implement a touch on the center button. He doesn't allows touch to proceed if the touch is detected too close to the center (in this case less than 40 px):

```
if (dist < 40 || dist > 100) 
{
    // forcing a tap to be on the ferrule
    NSLog(@"ignoring tap (%f,%f)", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    return NO;
}
```

**Here you have to implement your solution, for example:**

```
if (dist > 100) 
{
    // forcing a tap to be on the ferrule
    NSLog(@"ignoring tap (%f,%f)", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    return NO;
} else if (dist < 40) {
    [self.delegate didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:blablabla];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply , I think we are so close to solve , If My class is ViewController and in that following method is calling on clicked canter button as you tell me .-(void)cameraRecordButtonClick{

    [self.cameraUI  stopVideoCapture];
    [self.timer invalidate];
    
    NSLog(@"Camera instance is :::%@",self.cameraUI);
    self.timer =Nil;
}

Comment: In this method ,I am getting nil in print log

Comment: My Camera is coming nil . When I call above method which i write in comment . So camera delete method didfinish is not calling .Please help me

Comment: Do you implement method `-(void)didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` in your `ViewController`? And did you set your `ViewController` as delegate of cameraUI?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved my problem by using your post.